# Add items to Canvas Unity C#

Tags: c#, canvas, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add items to my Canvas dynamicly in C#.

Here is what I am trying to do

```
public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    private List<GameObject> _buttons;
    private GameObject _canvas;

    public MyScript()
    {
        _buttons = new List<GameObject>();
    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var button = Instantiate(Resources.Load("myButton", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
            if (button == null) continue;
            button.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position = new Vector3(i, i, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

I have my buttonPrefab which is inside of Canvas. After debug I see my new buttons created but they are not in Canvas and its normal because I didnt add them there in code. The point is that I dont have any idea how to add new buttons to Canvas.

Also how I can add OnClick event if buttons are GameObjects and I cant cast it to Button?

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 3):

Answering how to instantiate: when doing so, you need to rember about few things.

But first lets show some code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var button = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("myButton", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
            if (button == null) continue;
            button.transform.SetParent (referenceToCanvas.transform);
            button.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
            button.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler (Vector3.zero);
            button.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition3D = new Vector3(i, i, 0);

        }
```

When instatiating GameObjects Unity3D creates them in world space with given scale and rotation. When you set the canvas as parent sometimes the scale is set to zero or just not what you want. The same applies to rotation. So that is why I add these lines of code everytime I dynamicaly populate UI.

Of course `referenceToCanvas` is reference to canvas object ;)

Comment: How to create that reference?

Answer (score 1):

1-) In order to make new buttons added in Canvas you need to make your canvas object parent of these buttons, you need to use setParent method take a look at here
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html

2-)For your second question you can easily achieve that just add a collider to your object which you want to click and add a script to the object as well. And add OnMouseDown() method to this script, whenever you click this object this method will be called.

Answer (score 0):

For 1 see Burak, use `Transform.SetParent`.

For 2 I'd recommend creating an empty GameObject and add a UI Button to it and what ever you need in addition. Make this a prefab and instantiate it.