# Buttons without background, size, why?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want create menu with buttons. Template button is cloned and placed in vertical layout. It worked but in the middle of work there is strange effect of rendering only text child od button, additionally gameobjects do not have width, are outside of canvas. On the screen , in the center is my template button, goal is to have two columns of buttons on left and right side.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DivideDownUI : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {
        createBtnsRow(transform.Find("PanelLeft"));
        createBtnsRow(transform.Find("PanelRight"));
    }

    void createBtnsRow(Transform panel)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            GameObject btn = Instantiate(transform.Find("BtnTpl").gameObject);
            btn.transform.parent = panel;
            btn.SetActive(true);
            btn.transform.Find("Text").gameObject.GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + i;

        }
    }
}
```

`
[image: Editor view]

Resolved:
There was problem with positioning: After using rect transform instead of padding of layout group works as espected. [image: working :)]

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36042900/5115818

Comment: If you found a solution to your problem, please don't add it to your *question*. Instead, post it as an *answer*.